# XRM SetDisable doesn't work every time

Tags: javascript, field, dynamics-crm

I'm working with CRM, and I need to lock all fields (around 300) in a form using javascript.

I use this function :

```
var allAttributes = Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get();
for (var i in allAttributes) {
    var myattribute = Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get(allAttributes[i].getName());
    if (myattribute != null && myattribute != undefined && myattribute != '') {

        var myname = myattribute.getName();
        var myControl = Xrm.Page.getControl(myname);
        if (myControl != null && myControl != undefined && myControl != '')
            myControl.setDisabled(true);
    }
}
```

For most of them, it works, but some of fields are still editable in my form.
I debug it in Chrome step by step, and it appears that, on field that are not locked after my function, I did "`myControl.getDisabled()`", and it is set to true. but the field IS NOT lock on the form.

There isn't any other javascript running on these fields. I tried to delay my function call by 10s (using setTimeout), nothing change.

Any idea how I could lock every fields ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your fuction could be refactored to:

```
    var controls = Xrm.Page.ui.controls.get();
    for (var i in controls) 
    {
        if (controls[i].setDisabled != undefined)
        {
            controls[i].setDisabled(true);
        }
    }
```

Try this refactor, if after this it doesn't work please name the entity you are working and the fields not locked.

Comment: Your code will throw errors because not all the controls have setDisabled method. Sample - IFrames, subgrids and webresources.

Comment: To make this code work properly you can add just one line like if (typeof controls[i].setDisabled != "undefined")

Comment: @Andrii Butenko Thanks for your comment, i didn't test it for IFrames, but for webresources and subgrids it doesn't throw error, maybe the rollup and CRM version? I'm working on CRM 2011.

Comment: recheck this article - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334266%28v=crm.5%29.aspx It is for CRM 2011 and it is written that setDisabled is applicable for all controls except iFrames and WebResources. Do you think there is an error in SDK?

Comment: I don't really have an answer for that, this way doesn't throw errors but in case someone has problems i will update the script.